# Winform: get current_time from postgresql and display it in label?

Tags: c#, postgresql, winforms

I want to get current time in my database, display it in a label, and update every second.
Here I'm using current time of my computer:

```
public Main()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    timer1.Enabled = true;
    timer1.Interval = 1000;
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbTimer.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
}
```

But I want to change it to current time of my Postgre db. How to do it? Maybe something like this, of course it is not correct:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbTimer.Text = getServerTime();
}

public string getServerTime()
{
    string time = "";
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        string sql = "SELECT CURRENT_TIME";
        NpgsqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        time = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception msg)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(msg.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
    return time;
}
```

I think my query is correct but `time = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();` has value like `0001/01/01 HH:mm:ss`. So I want to know what I was wrong, and what is correct syntax to get the query result just `HH:mm:ss`.

Comment: What basically is your goal to display the server date/time to your winforms application?

Comment: @ngeksyo just to allow user to know the exact time in server. because my server's time is difference with client's time.

Comment: As far as I understand, you don't have any problem with WinForms part, all you need is the correct query. Perhaps, you can rephrase your question as: "How to query current date/time in PostgreSQL?". Actually, you can google exactly that, look through the official docs and then select the most appropriate function: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html

Comment: @defaultlocale I think my query is correct. but "time = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();" has value like "0001/01/01 HH:mm:ss". So I want to know what I was wrong, and what is correct syntax to get the query result just "HH:mm:ss".

Comment: @MinhHoàngCao Ahh, I see. You might want to post this explanation in the question itself.

Comment: @defaultlocale ok I will. Thanks.

Comment: Oh maybe I solved my problem. Thanks guys :))

Comment: @MinhHoàngCao Great! Remember, you can answer your own question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer Then you can accept your own answer, this will mark your question as "solved"

Comment: @MinhHoàngCao So every second you're going to create a new connection? Which will start a new process etc. This is so inefficient. Keep your connection open and use the same one every time.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. just change the code to :

```
string timestring = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
DateTime timer = DateTime.Parse(timestring);
time = timer.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand from [the documentation](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/datetime.html) `ExecuteScalar` should return a [`DateTimeOffset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTimeOffset.aspx) value for this query. If that's the case, you can call [`ToString(string format)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346136.aspx) directly on the value without parsing it. You just need to cast it.

Something like this should work (DISCLAIMER: untested code):

```
var currentTime = (DateTimeOffset) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
time = currentTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```